# How to change x-y perspective in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to rotate my x-y perspective as my car rotates in PyGame.

When I rotate my car to turn it, I want my `x-y` perspective to change too so the `forward` and `backward` movement of the car are unaffected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) to rotate an image respectively [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object by 90°:

```py
car_image = pygame.image.load("filname.png")
car_image = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image , 90)
```

---

PyGame uses a coordinate system where the top left corner is (0, 0). The y-axis points down and the x-axis points to the right. That cannot be changed.

Comment: But how can I rotate the perspective (coordinates), so that the y-axis still match with front of the car (like it does when the car is straight)

Comment: @RakshitJoshi You cannot change the pygame coordinates system. No way.